How do I tighten this screw at the bottom of an upright of a plate tree?
I'm wondering how to tighten this screw.
I can hold one side with a wrench, but the other side seems to require a screwdriver.
But with the wrench I get so much more leverage that it's impossible to hold the screw in place with the screwdriver (unless you have the grip strength of a machine.)
These are two screws on the upright of a plate tree, so I want to get this as flush as possible.




Why are you using a flat screwdriver in a Philips or crosshead screw?

Sorry, changed it. Not a flat head of course : )

Use a quality screwdriver then the final torque depends on your strength - I can shear screws too easily - but then you need to tighten to a sensible level anyway.

OK so what you're saying is no trick in this one, indeed it's a wrench and the correct screw driver, that should be enough to tighten it? OK, maybe then I need to check the screw driver again I used. I was able to get it reasonably tight, but thought somehow to get it even tighter would be better ...

Some screwdrivers have a hex on the shaft so you can use a spanner, or use a cordless drill and screwdriver bit.

Ah, I see, that's a great idea. Thanks! If you want, I would accept that as an answer, since it gave me a direction to continue.

I don't think you will get it "flush" with that washer under the screw head. That screw head looks like it is designed to be countersunk, i.e. to rest flush in a beveled hole; however, if there is a beveled hole you have covered it with a washer.

Also the question of if your Phillips is the correct size for the screw head - this eyeballs as possibly being a #3, so a #2 would not work well. There's also the possibility that it's one of the other "cross" forms, though I don't see a clear indication of that.

If that's a nylock nut, it'll need more torque on the bolt than a regular nut.  Also, you'll need the correct sized screwdriver.

OK looks like the consensus is to check the screwdriver isn't right, I'll check that again. Yeah it's a nylock nut. I don't really understand why they went for the two screws on the upright with this kind of screw with a Philips head, all the others for that plate tree are regular nuts/bolts.

This is probably a design error. The original fastener might have been a bolt, but during testing they found the bolt head touched the floor. It would be easier to change the bolt to a screw than to redesign everything else to make the bolt work.

That could actually be ... the bar which is at the bottom of the upright has very little clearance from the floor. Too little for a bolt. Is that a stability problem? Since as someone mentioned, it's unlikely that I'll be able to tighten the screw really tight. I plan to hang maybe 150 kg on that plate tree.

The right size screwdriver plus the wench should tighten the screw/nut enough.  All the weight will be pushing down, so the screw/nut is more to keep it together, than to hold weight.

OK, I'll get another screwdriver then. I checked yesterday, the one I used was too small I think. Thanks all, you all have been very helpful.
